# z-index not working with silverlight

Tags: html, silverlight

I'm embedding a page that hosts a silverlight application inside an IFRAM inside my html page. now I'm trying to display a div over the IFRAM (containing the silverlight page) using z-index but the div is always hidden under the  silverlight content. how can I achieve this?

Note: if I embed another page that doesn't use silverlight everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without code but something like this should do it.  Remember, when working with z-index, you have to have position explicitly set.

Also, you can actually target and style iframes like this:

```
<style>
    .iframe-wrapper iframe {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .foo {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
</style>
```

...

```
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
    <iframe ... />
</div>

<div class="foo">bar</div>
```